# Get Data from Web - 404 error

Tags: excel

I am trying to get data from a website into a table in Excel. I am just using the regular button (get data - from web) in Excel (No code) Works fine for two websites but for a different website I am getting the following error:

Details: "The remote server return an HTTP status code '404' when trying to access 'https://smarkets.com/listing/sport/football/premier-league-2017-2018'."

The webpage certainly exists - I am guessing this is a deliberate strategy by the website to prevent data harvesting.

Anyone have any idea how I can get round it either through the get data route or a VBA approach?

Thanks

JL

Comment: So you have a problem with some Excel setup or code, so why didn't you show any of it? I don't think there's much anyone can do with something this vague.

Comment: Because there is no code -  I press the get data (from web) button and input the website address. I have posted the resultant error code.

Comment: The page below probably resolves the issue you have... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206943/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-make-excel-access-a-web-query-via-https?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Link above didn't resolve as far as I can see. I tried testing settings with Postman to no avail. Also, tried querytable > nope. Might be best to wait for their API which is currently in closed alpha stage. You can apply for access but not sure about criteria blah blah...

Comment: Thanks - apparently it something to do with https - and as such doesn’t resolve through excel. I’ve got it working now through a rails approach. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Would be interesting to know how you got it to work that way. Any link to something related I could have a look at please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I inspected traffic with Fiddler and Postman to no avail and in the end contacted the team direct for an answer.

The short answer, from their API team, is no.

> Eventually our API, which may be suitable for your needs, will be
>   available to everyone.

API is in closed alpha stage as I mentioned in comments.  More information here: [API feed](http://API-Odds-Feed).

> API/Odds Feed We're currently working on a new streaming API that is
>   faster and more scalable. The API is currently in a closed alpha
>   stage. Unfortunately there is no timeframe on when we'll be able to
>   release it to the public.
>
> We will prioritise market makers when issuing streaming API accounts.
>   If you would like to gain alpha access to this service, you can apply
>   by outlining your proposal [here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1qI8RqypNimakPx-bmoUE_lA0YSP3YogKfL8N14STNSM/viewform?edit_requested=true)

You can gain access to their XML feed with [odds.smarkets.com/oddsfeed.xml](http://odds.smarkets.com/oddsfeed.xml) .

> The feed is updated every few seconds but the information is delayed
>   by 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks guys for looking at this! I’ve got it working now through Rails